# Xcode 13.4.1: Cannot find 'connectingSceneSession' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode13

I am pretty new in Swift programming. I am trying to make and Dicee App and suddenly I got this type of error: **Cannot find 'connectingSceneSession' in scope**

Xcode tell me that problem is in AppDelegate.swift file and the code is on the picture bellow or pasted under the picture.

[image]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
```

It is partly annoying to me, because I did nothing. I was trying to reopen project multiple times, I restarted Xcode too. I also set up a completely new project and this error appears immediately after I imported it from GitHub. DO you have any recommendations how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you import from GitHub?

Comment: Dicee App project from course resources.

Comment: Are you sure that `UIKit` is imported?

Comment: Yes absolutely. it is imported in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I was forced to rename main folder where was the project recloned.